# How do I display input change in a dialog in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dynamic, dialog

I got a dialog, which displays numbers. In the last row I want to display the sum of these 10 numbers, while the user changes these numbers. 
So for example if the user changes the 50 to 60 I want the last row to display 110.
What is a good way to implement that?
Following some html of the dialog:

[image]

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Rechenleistung anpassen</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="form">

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="number" #input placeholder="Leistung von Miner 1" formControlName="power1"
           required min="1" max="100">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-card-content>
    Die Leistung muss insgesamt 100 sein! Momentane Leistung: {{power1 + power2 + power3 + power4 +
    power5 + power6 + power7 + power8 + power9 + power10}}
  </mat-card-content>

</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="close()">Zurück</button>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="save()" cdkFocusInitial>Senden</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your html as follows :

```
 <mat-card-content>
    Die Leistung muss insgesamt 100 sein! Momentane Leistung: {{sum}}
  </mat-card-content>
```

create a variable which returns the sum and trigger this method after form is built:

```
populateSum() {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
    this.sum = this.form.get('power1').value +
    this.form.get('power2').value + this.form.get('power3').value + this.form.get('power4').value + this.form.get('power5').value + this.form.get('power6').value + this.form.get('power7').value + this.form.get('power8').value + this.form.get('power9').value + 
    this.form.get('power10').value
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get property in your component. suppose your form defined in your app.component.ts file. define a get property like below code:

```
get sum(){
  return this.form.get('power1').value + this.form.get('power2').value;
}
```

and your html file:

```
<mat-card-content>
    Die Leistung muss insgesamt 100 sein! Momentane Leistung: {{sum}}
</mat-card-content>
```

Comment: I think he needs all the values populated dynamically when changed. With the above it won't be dynamic for every instant.

Comment: why would you say that!? this is get property binding and every value change in form recalculate the sum property.
please test that code and see result!